# Validate European comma separated price in html form with REGEX

Tags: html, regex

I have a html form where users could insert a price. Allowed should be:

XX,XX

(X = digit)

So it should be allowed only with two digits before and two digits after the comma.

I tried:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.05" id="test" required>
```

Problem 1: It accepts even values that are separated via dot.

Problem 2: It accepts longer and shorter values.

I think I need a REGEX pattern value in the input field like:

```
pattern="^([1-9][1-9])(,[1-9][1-9])*$"
```

Any hints?

Comment: `[1-9]` will match a digit 1-9 and will not match a zero. Try `<input type="text" pattern="\d{2},\d{2}" id="test" required>`

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character class `[1-9]` does not match a zero and this part of the pattern `(,[1-9][1-9])*` will repeat 0 or more times a comma followed by again 2 digits 1-9.

In this case, the minimum is 11 without a comma, a for example `11,11,11,11` would also be a valid value.

The pattern attribute is already anchored, the code could look like

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{2},\d{2}" id="test" required>
```